# rails validation of uniqueness on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following validation rule on one of the models,

```
validates :reciept_num, :presence => true,
                        :numericality => { :only_integer => true },
                        :uniqueness => true,
                        :on => :update,
                        :if => "!status_id.nil?"`
```

Now, when I update the object using `update_attributes` method it gives me following error

`reciept_num: has already been taken`.

While updating the the object I'm not changing the reciept_num attribute? So, why does this validation fails on update?

If I'm not updating the value, it must be the old one and hence should pass validation. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, validations don't run based on whether the attribute has changed or not (unless of course you ask for that explicitly). Everytime a record with a uniqueness validation saves and the validation can run (as defined by `:on`, `:if`, `:unless` options) it will check whether there are any instances other than itself with the value that is supposed to be unique.

Since you've got conditions on your validation, I imagine you could end up creating two instances with the same receipt num, but where both have a null `status_id`. Set the `status_id` column and the validation kicks into action and finds the other instances.

Another thing is that since your validation is on update only you could create multiple instances with the same receipt num, again trying to update the record would trigger the validation.

I'm only guessing at the precise scenarios though.

Comment: thanks for your reply. after reading this it came to my mind the seed data i created had duplicate entries.

Comment: And, `:uniqueness => true` doesn't actually guarantee uniqueness even without the conditions, you need a unique constraint inside the database for that.

Comment: mu is too short, can you elaborate?

Comment: To elaborate on Mu's comments, here's the documentation of 'validates_uniqueness_of'. Pay special attention to the 'Concurrency and Integrity' section where it discusses when the app-level validations fall apart: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of